# PHP form delete from MYSQL table dont delete the right row

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a problem with my delete form. When you press the delete button it will always delete the last inserted row instead of the row you want to delete.
I am using a jQuery Ajax SendForm function to do the update on the div when you press delete. It worked before adding that function. It's only delete that doesn't work with the SendForm; You can do updates and it works just fine.

```
<?php     

  foreach ($pdo->query( 'SELECT * FROM Commenta order by commentID desc;'  ) as $row) :
      $luck = $row ['commentID'];
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><i class='fa fa-eye w3-blue w3-padding-tiny'></i></td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['alias']."</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        foreach($pdo->query( 'select realName from SubPlace, CommentSubPlace where SubPlace.name = CommentSubPlace.name and CommentSubPlace.commentID = '.$luck.';' ) as $brow){;
          echo $brow['realName']."</br>";
        };
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['grade']." / 5 </td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['kommentar']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>"; 
        ?>    

        <td class="comment-delete">
          <form id="cucdel">
            <input type="hidden" name="commentID" value="<?php echo $row['commentID']; ?>">
            <button type="button" onclick="SendForm('comments', 'comments', 'cucdel');">radera</button>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>

    <?php
  endforeach;
?>
```

The deletion portion of the code:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['commentID'])) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM Commenta WHERE commentID = :commentID";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':commentID', $_POST['commentID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Check in developers console which `commentID` is sent.

Comment: What is `SendForm`?  When you debug this, where/how specifically does it use the wrong Comment ID?

Comment: move the deletion code above the view/output so it deletes before it displays.  as mentioned by @david we must see the `function SendForm`.

Comment: `function SendForm(page, go, form) {
 
    $.ajax({
        url : 'includes/'+page+'.php', 
        type: 'POST',
  data: $("#"+form).serialize(), // serializes the form element.
  
        success: function(data){
            MakeRequest(go);  // the div that shall load after you run the function
        }
    });
}
` this is the sendForm function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
foreach($pdo->query( 'select realName from SubPlace, CommentSubPlace where SubPlace.name = CommentSubPlace.name and CommentSubPlace.commentID = '.$luck.';' ) as $brow){;
```

while not a syntax error - has no purpose in its semi colon.  the line can be made much more clear to you and programmers behind you if changed to:

```
// protect yourself from bad data
$luckint = (integer) $luck; 

// lose the confusing and unnecessary semi-colon here
// prepare the query separately
$query = 'select realName from SubPlace, CommentSubPlace where SubPlace.name = CommentSubPlace.name and CommentSubPlace.commentID = '.$luckint;  

// this line *can not* end in a semi-colon - find your error log
foreach ($pdo->query( $query ) as $brow) {
```

**answer to question**

the reason it's always deleting the last one is the **form id**.  you are always printing the same id to every delete form.  the id must be unique - make the form id like this:

```
<form id="cucdel<?php echo $row['commentID']; ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="commentID" value="<?php echo $row['commentID']; ?>">
 <button type="button" onclick="SendForm('comments', 'comments', 'cucdel<?php echo $row['commentID']; ?>');">radera</button>
</form>
```

and then update the

Comment: *"has a syntax error - it should not end in a semi colon"* - That is both incorrect and correct. The semi-colon in PHP is valid character. All it does is that it "ends the statement" as per http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php *"As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be terminated with a semicolon at the end of each statement. The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block...."* - and therefore would not throw an error per se.

Comment: @WEBjuju if you use the same sendForm function to du a update with a drop down select list are there any thing you need to do diffrent?

Comment: like `<form id="cucupdate<?php echo $row['commentID']; ?>">` maybe?  did this solve the issue?  please mark as solved to help other people.